# Swift Generics: function with T.Type as parameter returns optional T

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I'm attempting to write a series of generic functions that will sort through a stack of viewControllers by passing a `UIViewController` class or subclass Type and then either return the instance of the "found" viewController or nil. So far I have been unable to even get this simple snippet to compile:

```
extension UINavigationController {

    func fhk_find<T: UIViewController>(viewControllerType: T.Type) -> T?
    {
        if let viewController = viewControllers.first as? viewControllerType {
            return viewController
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

and would call:

```
navController.fhk_find(fooViewController.self)
```

However, the compiler is telling me that `viewControllerType` is not a type.

I'm not exactly sure what I'm missing here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to cast the `viewControllers.first` (in case it exist) to `T`, rather than to the parameter `viewControllerType`. In fact, you won't need to make use of this parameter at all; you can modify your extension to the following:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    func fhkFindFirst<T: UIViewController>(_: T.Type) -> T? {
        for viewController in viewControllers {
            if let viewController = viewController as? T {
                return viewController
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Example usage follows below. Note that you call with `fooViewController.dynamicType` rather than `fooViewController.self`. The latter gives you the *value* of `fooViewController.self` rather than the type, i.e., `fooViewController.self = fooViewController.self`.

Now note, however, that an attempted conversion from a subclass type to its superclass will always succeed, so the solution above will correctly identify subclass instances (subclasses of `UIViewController`), whereas if you query for a superclass instance (i.e., `T` as superclass `UIViewController`) then `viewController = viewController as? T` will always succeed even if `viewController` is in fact an instance of a subclass of `UIViewController`.

---

**Using `fhkFindFirst(...)` to identify subclass instances: OK**

In the following example two subclass instances are correctly identified and their references returned to caller.

```
class FooViewController : UIViewController { }
class BarViewController : UIViewController { }

let fooViewController = FooViewController()
let barViewController = BarViewController()

let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: fooViewController)
navController.addChildViewController(barViewController)

print(navController.fhkFindFirst(fooViewController.dynamicType) ?? "None found.")
// or: print(navController.fhkFindFirst(FooViewController))
/* <__lldb_expr_1582.FooViewController: 0x7fb97840ad80> */

print(navController.fhkFindFirst(barViewController.dynamicType) ?? "None found.")
// or: print(navController.fhkFindFirst(BarViewController))
/* <__lldb_expr_1582.BarViewController: 0x7fb978709340> */
```

---

**Using `fhkFindFirst(...)` to find superclass instances: not as intended**

Whereas in the following case, `fooViewController` is an `UIViewController` object, and is mis-identified as a `BarViewController`, since type conversion of of `BarViewController` object (in `UINavigationController.viewControllers`) to `UIViewController` succeeds.

```
class BarViewController : UIViewController { }

let fooViewController = UIViewController()
let barViewController = BarViewController()

let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: barViewController)
navController.addChildViewController(fooViewController)

print(navController.fhkFindFirst(fooViewController.dynamicType) ?? "None found.")
// or: print(navController.fhkFindFirst(UIViewController))
    /* <__lldb_expr_1533.BarViewController: 0x7fa519e2bd40> <-- "wrong" one */

print(navController.fhkFindFirst(barViewController.dynamicType) ?? "None found.")
// or: print(navController.fhkFindFirst(BarViewController))
    /* <__lldb_expr_1533.BarViewController: 0x7fa519e2bd40> */
```

---

To wrap up; the above will work as long as you only use the method to search for subclasses of `UIViewController`; whereas if you try to search for a superclass object, you will get the first controller in `UINavigationController.viewControllers`.

---

*Addition with regard to edelaney05:s related question in comments below*

I'll start by quoting the question in case the comment were to be deleted:

> **edelaney05:** Is there a way to guard against this? This is a pretty interesting edge case to consider especially if you've got an
>   intermediate class. `class FooVC: AwesomeVC { ... }`, `class BarVC: AwesomeVC { ... }`, and `class AwesomeVC: UIViewController { ... }`.

*Yes*, you can work around this behaviour, in case you know you'll be working with other than only pure (1st-level) subclasses of `UIViewController`; say, to allow for finding first instance of

- Subclasses to `UIViewController`.              (+)
- Subclasses to these subclasses.                (++)

We can make use of dynamic type comparison to ensure that we don't perform a conversion of a subclass instance to its superclass (and hence misidentifying a subclass instance as the superclass instance we're looking for).

```
extension UINavigationController {
    func fhkFindFirst<T: UIViewController>(_: T.Type) -> T? {
        for viewController in viewControllers {
            if let supClassType = viewController.superclass?.dynamicType where supClassType != T.Type.self {
                if let viewController = viewController as? T {
                    return viewController
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

class FooBarViewController: UIViewController { }

class FooViewController : FooBarViewController { }
class BarViewController : FooBarViewController { }

let fooBarViewController = FooBarViewController()
let fooViewController = FooViewController()
let barViewController = BarViewController()

let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: fooViewController)
navController.addChildViewController(barViewController)
navController.addChildViewController(fooBarViewController)

print(navController.fhkFindFirst(FooViewController) ?? "None found.")
/* <__lldb_expr_1582.FooViewController: 0x7fe22a712e40> */

print(navController.fhkFindFirst(BarViewController) ?? "None found.")
/* <__lldb_expr_1582.BarViewController: 0x7fe22a4196a0> */

print(navController.fhkFindFirst(FooBarViewController) ?? "None found.")
/* <__lldb_expr_1582.FooBarViewController: 0x7fe22a70ee60> */
```

Comment: Ah! I knew it would be something simple. Thank you! And thanks for saving me the future headache by pointing out .self vs .dynamicType.

Comment: @StephenNewton Happy to help. Also note that I updated you extension method to follow the Swift `camelCase` naming convention for method names.

Comment: @StephenNewton Note my edit: the solution above works fine as long as you only search for subclass instances of `UIViewController`, but will always return first instance in `UINavigationController.viewControllers` if you attempt to search for a superclass object (`UIViewController`). This should be OK, however, as all you viewcontrollers should be instances of subclasses of `UIViewController`.

Comment: @dfri is there a way to guard against this? This is a pretty interesting edge case to consider especially if you've got an intermediate class. `class FooVC: AwesomeVC { ... }`, `class BarVC: AwesomeVC { ... }`, and `class AwesomeVC: UIViewController { ... }`

Comment: @edelaney05 Yes, we can work around this; see edited answer above.